# Which commands does LyX run to generate PDF (pdflatex) and other export formats?

Tags: lyx, pdf

What commands should I run manually to repeat all the steps LyX makes to generate a final output (like pdflatex PDF) for a specific document? I need it for using in a report generator written in another language.

I've looked into "LaTeX Log", but is seems like having outputs of commands, not commands itself.

Comment: What commands LyX runs is complicated and depends on the document. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do? From the other language, can you just call LyX from the command line? For example, `lyx -e pdf2 yourfile.lyx` will produce a PDF file with LyX. You can often run external commands from languages with a `system` command.

Comment: @scottkosty I make a template in LyX and export it to .tex. Then I replace placeholders in .tex with certain TeX code and save the modified .tex file. Now, I want to run a command that would export this .tex to .pdf. And since the template was done in LyX, I see it natural to use the same set of commands as if I made .lyx → .pdf export. You advised using `lyx`, but can I run this: `lyx -e pdf2 yourfile.tex`?

Comment: Thanks for the extra details. `lyx -e pdf2 yourfile.tex` will not work. You could input external material by using Insert > File > Child Document. Or if you want something more customizable Insert > File > External Material (see Help > Customization for more information on this). Or you could use Python to do substitutions: http://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/PLyXSystem or you could do the substitutions directly in the .lyx file (it has its own format but it's just text) and then use `lyx -e pdf2 yourfile.lyx`.

Comment: @scottkosty The idea about editing .lyx directly is simple and effective. Great solution. I actually use R for substitutions.

Comment: Interesting, do you use `readLines` and `gsub` ?

Comment: @scottkosty I use `for` cycle on a named list like `inputs$name = ""` to replace all instances like `{{name}}`, with `gregexpr` and `regmatches`. And, yes, `readLines` for reading the template. A good alternative is `whisker.render`, which does replacement automatically if `{{{name}}}` is used.

Comment: `whisker.render` looks useful. My final suggestion/question is why don't you use `knitr` (which LyX has built-in support for)?

Comment: @scottkosty `knitr` (call it "R in LaTeX") allows making one report at a time, while "LaTeX in R" allows me making multiple documents at a time with more flexibility regarding the structure, testing, and output. Though maybe I'm wrong regarding `knitr`—I couldn't set it up properly for minor errors.

Comment: Good answer. You are right that that's not `knitr`'s purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit the LyX file directly. It is a text file. Then run

```
lyx -e pdf2 yourfile.lyx
```

to produce a PDF file using pdflatex.

Comment: But as I see now, my plan failed: I can't work with .lyx file as if it were .tex. I.e., .lyx file has `\begin_layout Title` instead of `\begin{title}` and so forth, so when I insert tex code in .lyx file, it returns an error on `lyx -e pdf2 yourfile.lyx` because only native LyX coding is supported. One option is to exclude all LyX coding (as if "Insert TeX" on the whole document), but then I lose all advantages of LyX as a TeX editor. Or another option is: Create a template in .lyx → Export to .tex → Replace placeholders → Save result as .lyx → Run `lyx -e pdf2 yourfile.lyx`.

Comment: Can I convert .tex file to .pdf via `lyx` program? Something like `lyx -e pdf2 texfile.tex`? (It doesn't work.)

Comment: @Anton LyX works on `.lyx` files. It is not a LaTeX editor. LaTeX is just one of the formats it can export to. It can also import `.tex` files (use the stand-alone program `tex2lyx` from the commandline) but I do not recommend the approach of export to .tex, edit and then import the .tex file because it can be very tricky to parse LaTeX so it's hard for LyX to import .tex files. If you want to input LaTeX code, use ERT. If you need to do this a lot, I would recommend a LaTeX editor instead of LyX.